# Как отобразить разницу данных пользователей в первый приход и во второй?

Tags: sql

Извиняюсь, за плохо сформированный вопрос. Но суть сейчас объясню.

Есть таблица с записями где около 200к записей. Все они сформированы в 5 колонок. 
В них входит (айди, пол, дата, причина, следствие). Вот пример таких записей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице по 2 записи для каждого айди. Т.е. например :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как видно каждое айди в таблице встречается 2 раза. Одно раньше, другое позже по дате (в одну дату невозможно). Как правильно посчитать например такое:
Отобразит всех людей у кого в первый раз *Polyps.* и *normal* а во второй раз *CRC* и *Futher Procedure* ?

Comment: А почему id в таком порядке записаны? Почему не цифрами? Если каждая запись имеет свою цифру ты облегчишь же себе дело

Comment: `Отобразить всех людей` - что именно нужно отобразить? Где "люди"?

Comment: укажите точный диалект sql, что за СУБД тО?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно заджойнить таблицу саму на себя по условию совпадения id и увеличения даты. А потом указать нужные условия для каждой таблицы.

```
SELECT
  t1.`id`
FROM
  mytable t1
  JOIN mytable t2 ON (
    t1.`id` = t2.`id` AND
    t1.`date` < t2.`date`
  )
WHERE
  t1.`field` = 'Polyps.' AND t1.`field2` = 'normal' AND
  t2.`field1` = 'CRC' AND t2.`field2` = 'Futher Procedure'
```

Comment: мб лучше сначала две выборки с условиями сделать, а потом их заджойнить?

Comment: @teran чем лучше?

Comment: так наджойнить 100к записей, которые потом будут фильтроваться. А если сначала отфильтровать, то мб там останется всего  пару тысяч чтобы поджойнить. Или мб вообще `intersect` применить

Comment: @teran Там INNER JOIN. Даже в самом худшем работе оптимизатора, вначале отфильтруются данные по первой таблице, потом к ним приджойнятся данные из второй таблицы и опять отфильтруются. Т.е. в моем случае джойн никак не влияет на выборку из первой таблицы и сокращает выборку из второй за счет дополнительной фильтрации по `id` и дате

Answer (score 0):

под Oracle будет выглядеть так

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM SCOTT.TAB1 t1
LEFT JOIN SCOTT.TAB1 t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  AND TO_DATE(t1.DAT, 'yyyy/mm/dd') < TO_DATE(t2.DAT, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
WHERE t1.CAUSE = 'Polyps.'
  AND t1.EFFECT = 'normal'
  AND t2.CAUSE = 'CRC'
  AND t2.EFFECT = 'Futher Procedure';
```

Comment: левый то джоин зачем?

Comment: я его по умолчанию всегда использую, можно и без него